# WordPress Progress Bar loading to fast and not disappearing after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using WordPress to manage content on a website and I recent installed a WordPress plugin called [Progress Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/progress-bar/) to show the progress for content loading on one of the pages. However I have been trying to apply some css styles and java functions with such for the former. I am able to float the progress bar anywhere on the page but I cannot make slow down the rate of loading the bar. I also cannot make the bar disappear once it is fully loaded. Can you please help? Here are the snippets containing my codes:

```js
$("#locator").animate({
    width: "100%"
}, 20000, function() {
    $(#locator).closest('#locator').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#locator { position:absolute; visibility:show; left: 380px; top: 330px; z-index:200; }
```

```html
<div id="locator">[wppb progress=100 option="animated-candystripe orange"]</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually decided the best way to go was to hide the progress bar with css so I created an external css style sheet called it from ui.R. Here is the css code:

**style.css**

```
.shiny-file-input-progress {display: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

One obvious point is that you are missing quotation marks:

```
$('#locator').closest('#locator').fadeOut();
```